# Can I use a JavaScript Alert box to show a countdown timer?

Tags: javascript, alert

I would like to display a `count down timer` in an `alert` box.

When the page loads, the alert should appears, counting down. 

When it reaches zero, the alert should disappear automatically, and the user can proceed to view the page.

Can this be achieved using an `alert` box?

Example link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329203/javascript-alert-box-which-shows-countdown-timer)

Comment: Well you can not use an alert to start if that is what you want to happen.

Comment: countdown time run in alert to view the page

Comment: I'd look into an overlay `div` to display countdown over the top of the page content, which can be hidden after countdown finishes. Alert cannot do what you are asking for.

Comment: then what is the way to solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to use an alert dialog to do what you want. `window.alert` can only display static text and must be actioned by the user before it will go away (i.e. they must click on "OK")

However, what you can do instead is to put a "blanket" over the page which is essentially a `<div>` tag styled with CSS to full width and height, fixed position, and a z-index higher than everything on the page. Optionally you can also apply an opacity setting so the page is still visible. This blanket prevents users from interacting with page elements.

On top of that you can put another `<div>` which has an even higher z-index in which you can place your timer element.

You can update your timer with the `setInterval` Javascript method, and upon reaching 0, it can remove the blanket and timer div and stop and clear the interval timer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `div` to overlay your page content until the countdown has ended.

Append the new div to the page, and then change it's `display` CSS property to `none` to hide it after five seconds. 

`HTML` and `CSS` below are just for example, they represent your own current content, obviously.

It can be done like this -

**HTML** Just for example's sake.

```
<div id="examplecontent"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#examplecontent {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = Show_Countdown;
var counter = 5;

function Show_Countdown() {

    var countDown_overlay = 'position:absolute;' +
        'top:50%;' +
        'left:50%;' +
        'background-color:white;' +
        'z-index:1002;' +
        'overflow:auto;' +
        'width:400px;' +
        'text-align:center;' +
        'height:400px;' +
        'margin-left:-200px;' +
        'margin-top:-200px';

    $('body').append('<div id="overLay" style="' + countDown_overlay + '"><span id="time"></span></div>');

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = counter;
        counter = (counter - 1);

        if (counter < 0) 
        {            
            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById("overLay").style.display = 'none';
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```

To go a bit further, you should disable/enable your background content dependant on whether the overlay is displayed.

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f4ngbagm/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this...

```
// 1. Display an alert dialog with the content: "Warning! This message will self-destruct in"
alert("Warning! This message will self-destruct in")

// 2. Display a "3... 2... 1..." countdown using 3 alert dialog boxes
alert("3...")
alert("2...")
alert("1...")

// 3. This statement selects the <h1> element and replaces its text with "BOOM!".
document.querySelector("h1").textContent = "BOOM!";

// 4. Log "Message destroyed!" to the console
```